# How to understand 'with a bit of luck' in this sentence?

Tags: expressions

This is a quote from a comment on the movie *Like Sunday, like rain* :

> With a bit of luck Whaley was looking to cast the philandering, grubby musician who is messing up Eleanor’s life.

FYI, Whaley is the director of the movie.

This sentence feels a bit off for me. I think *with a bit of luck* implies 'luckily, one could have the ability to do something'. And *look to* means he was just *trying* to find an actor. I don't understand why would he need luck to *try* to cast the role? Shouldn't it be 'with a bit of luck, he casted the musician'?

Comment: With a bit of luck here means *relying on luck*. Luckily means he was *it was lucky that* something happened (which did not happen yet).

Comment: It might be a difficult role to cast, so a bit of luck is needed to find the right actor. As for *looking to*, please see Lexico's [**look to**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/look) **4.1** Hope or expect to do something. *He was looking to cast the musician*.

Comment: "Casted" is not a word.